# Repeat first layer column headers in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, excel-2016

Currently my pivot table contains column headers like this:

[image]

But I would like the first layer of headers to repeat itself, so that it looks like this:

[image]

Is there an option for Pivot Tables to do this? I tried going into Design > Report Layout > Repeat all item labels, but that only appears to repeat row headers, not columns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found this via: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repeat-item-labels-in-a-pivottable-882bdb55-9cdc-4d8d-b531-8e96e41dea31

1. Right-click the row or column label you want to repeat, and click Field Settings.
2. Click the Layout & Print tab, and check the Repeat item labels box.
3. Make sure Show item labels in tabular form is selected.

Tested just now and it worked for column headers.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Alan. I don't have 'Field Settings' when I right-click the label I want to repeat. It only shows "Value Field Settings", and I wonder if its because that header I'm trying to target is a measure field.

Comment: @sudden_clarity_clarence AFAIK Measure Fields are only available on Power-Pivot tables which I haven't got on my Excel 2016 so I'm unable to help I'm afraid :o(

Comment: @sudden_clarity_clarence, this doesn't work for the value fields. I had the same issue and when I put the month label above the values, this worked.  It isn't the order I'd prefer, but it will work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work today by following these steps:

- right click on the row
- choose Pivot Table Options
- click on the Printing Tab
- checkmark 'Set Print Titles'

Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on simple data by the following steps:
1-  Right-click the `Product A`
2-  Choose `Field Setting …` 
3-  Go to `Layout and Print`
4-   Add a check mark to `Repeat item labels`
You can see steps in the  following image:

**First Step:**
[image]

**Second Step:**
[image]